# How do I handle a multiple select form field in Perl?

Tags: perl, forms, select, cgi

What is the best, in Perl, way to get the selected values of a multiple select form field?

```
<select name="mult" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Opt. 1</option>
   <option value="2">Opt. 2</option> <!-- selected -->
   <option value="3">Opt. 3</option> 
   <option value="4">Opt. 4</option> <!-- selected -->
   <option value="5">Opt. 5</option>
</select>
```

I get regular form fields like this: `$param1 = param('param1');`

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you tried reading the CGI.pm docs? It tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Not to be rude, but are you honestly suggesting it's more efficient to wade through 59 pages (no joke) of CGI.pm docs, rather than post a quick question & get help from some extremely knowledgeable friendly people who might save him a few hours tearing his hair out? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) Module (and I really hope you are) then you can access the multiple values by assigning the param hash to an array and CGI does the rest. So in your example:

```
my @mult = $q->param('mult');
```

will store the selected values `(2, 4)` in the `@mult` array.